# What is $Y^n$ space?

Tags: vector-spaces

In Nikolay Yaremenko's paper: [here](https://globaljournals.org/GJSFR_Volume17/2-Electromagnetic-theory-from-standpoint.pdf), he mentions $Y^n$ space.  Is this just another term for $\mathbb R^n$ space?  If not, what is it?

Comment: The author constructs the space in the paper. So no, it's not real space.

Comment: So it's just a hypothetical space which he constructs and tries to prove.  Thanks.

Comment: I observe that in Section II ("Mathematical Description of the Space Structure $Y^n$") there are no $Y$s or $n$s.

Comment: I find the paper unclear

Answer (score 1):

$Y^{n - 1}$ represents the second fundamental tensor of hyperspaces. Yaremenko derives relevant equations for hyperspaces $Y^{n - 1}$ with non-zero torsion.